# How do I change webpack dev server's default port from 8080 to a different port?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I just started learning ReactJS, and so I'm quite a bit raw. Part of the course I'm following involves setting up the webpack dev server, and so far it's been fine. However, I can't get to preview what I'm doing (everything is being compiled successfully), in the browser, as I have another application (APACHE) running on 8080. As such, I would like to change the web packs port from its default 8080 to a different port like say 9000. I've spent a while looking for a solution but there doesn't seem to be a clear way on how to go around this.

If it helps, here is my basic webpack.config code:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + "/app/index.html",
    filename: "index.html",
    inject: "body"
});

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        "./app/index.js"
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "index_bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use the `devServer.port` option in the webpack config.

```
devServer: {
  port: 9000
}
```

Alternatively you can use the `--port` CLI option instead of changing your webpack config. So you'd run it like this:

```
webpack-dev-server --port 9000 [other options]
```

Answer (score 7):

I added `"start": "webpack-dev-server --port 8085"` under `"scripts"` object in `package.json` to change default webpack dev server port to `8085`.

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --port 8085",
  "build": "webpack --mode=production",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer above: I use the CLI with **--port ${1:-8080}** that way I have a default and I can specify at run time